# Error when SQL-querying flatfiles with custom file-extension

Tags: sql, ms-access, database-schema, ado

I'm looking for a way to query flatfiles with **custom** file-extensions directly via SQL.

Normally use something like

`SELECT * FROM [Text;DATABASE=C:\Flatfiles].[S7121070_ppis#csv]`

which works terrific with .txt, .csv and .tab.

However, in my current project I work with fixed-width flatfiles with an .ftp7-extension. When querying those files in with VBA, I encounter Err# -2147217911, stating that the object or database is locked.

Oddly, this occurs only whenever I querying anything that's **not** a .txt, .csv or .tab. Meaning `myfile.ftp7`, `myfile.ftp`, `myfile.abc` or `myfile` can't be queried.

Can't this be done or am I simply missing something? Thanks for your help!
Cheers, 
Martin

Additional Info:

- I use either Excel or Access with VBA
- Renaming .ftp7 to .csv, .txt, .tab solves the problem, but is a no-no due to read-only access
- I can use a `schema.ini`-files to describe the data-structure, so i would have expected that the actual file-extension is more or less redundant for interpreting the files contents

Comment: You may need to edit the registry (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/630ed1d9-73f1-4cc0-bc84-04f29cffc13b/what-registry-keys-are-responsible-for-file-extension-association?forum=netfxbcl) only certain extensions are allowed in MS Access.

Comment: @Fionnuala great hint, thank you! I'm no admin - however, I'll make sure to test this out at home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As postet by `Fionnuala`:
[Editing the registry](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/630ed1d9-73f1-4cc0-bc84-04f29cffc13b/what-registry-keys-are-responsible-for-file-extension-association?forum=netfxbcl) seems to solve the problem.