# Access VBA - Export .csv module, custom file name

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access

I have problem with my Access Export to .csv module. Everything works fine in other parts like importing one list, importing second list, doing query and export **IF** I do not change my output file name, I am lost and don't know why changing output filename cause Access to showing Error:

**Runtime Error: 3027:
Cannot update. Database or object is read-only.**

Everything works fine If output file stay default.

Module code below:

```
Public Sub exportQuery(exportSQL As String)
Dim db As DAO.Database, qd As DAO.QueryDef
Dim fd As FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

Set db = CurrentDb

'Check to see if querydef exists
For i = 0 To (db.QueryDefs.Count - 1)
    If db.QueryDefs(i).Name = "tmpExport" Then
        db.QueryDefs.Delete ("tmpExport")
        Exit For
End If
Next i

Set qd = db.CreateQueryDef("tmpExport", exportSQL)

'Set intial filename
fd.InitialFileName = "Deduplicated list_" & Format(Date, "mmddyyy") & ".csv"

If fd.Show = True Then
    If Format(fd.SelectedItems(1)) <> vbNullString Then
        DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "tmpExport", fd.SelectedItems(1), True
    End If
End If

'Cleanup
db.QueryDefs.Delete "tmpExport"
db.Close
Set db = Nothing
Set qd = Nothing
Set fd = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you changing the file extension from .csv to something different? Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40548303/error-when-sql-querying-flatfiles-with-custom-file-extenstion

Comment: Thank You for providing solution. I have answered with function which append filename with .csv extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SORRY: Didn't notice that **@Andre** in comment above provide me a solution. Thank You very much

Okay, I find the solution. The problem was, when You type in custom name IT MUST HAVE .csv extension. I implement function which appends filename with .csv

```
Function getCSVName(fileName As String) As String
Dim pos As Long
pos = InStrRev(fileName, ".")
If (pos > 0) Then
fileName = Left$(fileName, pos - 1)
End If
getCSVName = fileName & ".CSV"

End Function
```

And use it in Export module:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "tmpExport", getCSVName(fd.SelectedItems(1)), True
```

Comment: np, it was just a wild guess from my side. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine and works for me locally, when I enter an easy SQL command in the code above. 
I would recommend to check the SQL command which you try to execute.

Comment: Thank You. The problem was in extension of output file. I submit answer and now all works like a charm.